# Select with all options checkbox in Select2 JS?

Tags: php, jquery-select2

Need Select data with all options checkbox using Select2 JS. I tried to select all options in Select2 JS using checkbox and default select All Options.How to Set default All options Checked in Select2 JS.

**Script code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-select2").select2({
        closeOnSelect : false,
        placeholder : "Placeholder",
        allowHtml: true,
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true // создает новые опции на лету
    });

</script>
```

**Html Code:**

```
<select class="js-select2" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="O1" data-badge="">Option1</option>
            <option value="O2" data-badge="">Option2</option>
            <option value="O3" data-badge="">Option3</option>
            <option value="O4" data-badge="">Option4</option>
            <option value="O5" data-badge="">Option5</option>
            <option value="O6" data-badge="">Option6</option>
            <option value="O7" data-badge="">Option7</option>
            <option value="O8" data-badge="">Option8</option>
            <option value="O9" data-badge="">Option9</option>
            <option value="O10" data-badge="">Option10</option>
            <option value="O11" data-badge="">Option11</option>
            <option value="O12" data-badge="">Option12</option>
            <option value="O13" data-badge="">Option13</option>
        </select>
```

Need to select like,

[Select all Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T45xu.png)

Comment: Could you please show us some code.

Comment: Please check above my code

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create the Checkbox yourself next to select box.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All
```

Then you will need to bind the click event of this checkbox to select all the options of select2 dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-select2").select2({
        closeOnSelect : false,
        placeholder : "Placeholder",
        allowHtml: true,
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true // создает новые опции на лету
    });

    $("#checkbox").click(function(){ //Bind the Click event of Checkbox
        if($('#checkbox').is(':checked') ){ //If checkbox is checked. Select All Items.
            $(".js-select2 > option").prop("selected","selected");
            $(".js-select2").trigger("change");
        }else{ //Otherwise Deselect all items.
             $(".js-select2").val(null).trigger('change');
         }
    });

    $("#checkbox").click();  //Manually click the checkbox so that it is selected 1st time.
});
```

You can check the Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d6n2oaw1/)

Comment: thanq so much for your reply, Please see my attachment I need to select all option like above image.

Comment: This is not supported by Select2. You will need to write CSS to change select box to checkboxes.